# Ways to get the external db data without hitting it multiple times for multi page application in java

Tags: java, performance

I am working on one application (spring +hibernate) which has multiple pages.

I have one requirement where I have to fetch data based on user selection from external DB.
Now i want this data in some of the pages which might not be in sequence

one  approach to do that is .. I can save the details which i am getting from external db into my db and fetch it from my db through hibernate.

Other approach could be storing it into session variable, but I feel it is not a good practice.

Is there any other way to get the data without hitting external db multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to answer few questions like below.

- How frequently your external database changes and do you care about those changes if you are preparing your own database?

If you don't care about updates in external db or updates are not frequent, you can run a periodic job which synchs external db with your database every few hours or every night.

If this is too frequent and you care about those updates, I guess periodic synching isn't an option.

- What is the size of data you need to cache or get from external database?

If the data is small enough. Whenever you load some data, just keep it in local filesystem cache or even in-memory or session. You can evict the cache based on time or using LRU or LFU.